# Is onCreate called when an Activity object is created?

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate

Is `onCreate()` called when a class object that `extends Activity` is created? Or is it only called when an activity is *started*, for example over `startActivity(...)`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To answer you question, for a class that extends activity, if you try to instantiate that Activity by normal means ( MyActivity ma = new MyActivity(); )  the onCreate() method WILL NOT be called.   Only if you start the Activity with an intent will the method be called.

Comment: What happens when recreate() is called?

Comment: For that matter MyActivity ma = new MyActivity();  does this have any use or significance? I think any operation related to activity happens when an activity is started through an Intent.

Answer (score 15):

According to the developer.android.com the onCreate get called when activity is started. see details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

[image: States of an activity]

Answer (score 3):

> Each activity in an application goes through its own lifecycle.
>   Once and only once when an activity is created, is the onCreate() function executed.

Check this [Activity Life Cycle](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1646053&seqNum=2)

Answer (score 2):

i think that in Android , you cant write something like this :

```
AClassThatExtendedAnActivity instance = new AClassThatExtendedAnActivity();
```

the only way that you can use to launch an activity is passing with an intent to start your activity .

the creation of the instance is encapsulated on the `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` when you override the method `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);`

Regards ,

Comment: But we have learned in OOPs that only way to access the methods of a class is through the object of the class, so isn't this against that? Please throw some light into this.

Comment: We do not call the onCreate() method ; it is called automatically when you start an Activity from intent.

Comment: I understand that, but suppose there is a public method. methodXYZ() in Activity A and I can call this method from another activity say Activity B in its onCreate() so is there any use for this kind of pattern?

Comment: This kind of pattern is useless and you should avoid it. in order to call a public methode from another activity, i think it depends on what do want to do in that method, i.e you can use startActivityForResult, or use callbacks pattern to communicate between the two activities. I think you should throw an eye on this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666572/how-to-call-a-method-in-another-activity-from-activity.

Comment: I understand that it is useless, but if we are coming from the OOPs world, isn't that we have been taught? I think I never read about a call back method in the OOPs concepts, so if I were a newbie into android say with an OOPs background, then is there any intuitive way I could understand these concepts intuitively?