# how to call a method in another Activity from Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm developing an Android Application in which I have

I've two classes class A and Class B.

In class A, I tried the code Snippets like below,

How do I call a method in another Activity from Activity?

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {  

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
    }      

    public void method() {
        // some code
    }  
}

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {  

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main2);
    
        FirstActivity fact = new FIrstActivity();
    
        fact.method();
    }
}
```

Comment: You definitely need to read this - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html

Answer (score 20):

The startActivityForResult pattern is much better suited for what you're trying to achieve : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

Try below code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  

    Button button1;  
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
        textView1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View arg0) {  
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);  
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);// Activity is started with requestCode 2  
            }  
        });  
    }  
 // Call Back method  to get the Message form other Activity  
    @Override  
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
       {  
                 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
                  // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
                   if(requestCode==2)  
                         {  
                          //do the things u wanted 
                         }  
     }  

}
```

SecondActivity.class

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {  

    Button button1;  
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);  

            button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
            button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
                @Override  
                public void onClick(View arg0) {  
                    String message="hello ";  
                    Intent intent=new Intent();  
                    intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",message);  
                    setResult(2,intent);  
                    finish();//finishing activity  
                }  
            });  
    }  

}
```

Let me know if it helped...

Comment: How to get the `MESSAGE` in  `MainActivity` inside `requestCode==2` block? please explain.

Comment: From the intent(parm of onActivityResult) you can get extras.

Answer (score 13):

You should not create an instance of the activity class. It is wrong. Activity has ui and lifecycle and activity is started by `startActivity(intent)`

You can use `startActivityForResult` or you can pass the values from one activity to another using intents and do what is required. But it depends on what you intend to do in the method.

Comment: so how to call a method form another activity.

Comment: @user2932841 you can't what is that you are trying to do in that method?

Comment: @user2932841 you seem to have asked this question again. seems like a duplicate. But still what do you want to do in the method can you specify that?

Comment: You recommend, or at least mention, the use of Intents. On the other (duplicate) question the most popular answer recommends using a callback method in the Activity. I wonder if you'd be so kind as to explain what the advantages and disadvantages of using Intents vs. callbacks can be?

Comment: @RenniePet startActivityForResult can be used if you are waiting reults from one activity. If you see the other answer its a non activity class. I do admit i made a mistake by marking it a duplicate cause that is from a non-activity class. I have a re-opened the question.

Comment: Thanks for reply. My comment was because I've become very unsure of whether a callback method is an acceptable way to call a method in an Activity. Using an Intent is obviously the "correct" way - Google describes how to do it. And using a callback somehow seems "too easy", like it's "cheating". But is is OK, or are there situations where the use of a callback will cause problems, for example due to there being something wrong with the Activity's context, or something?

Comment: Startactivity for result should be used if you need results from another activity. You can use callbacks when you wants results for asynctask or worker fragment

Comment: `startActivityForResult` deprecated long long time ago

Answer (score 5):

If you need to call the same method from both Activities why not then use a third object?

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity 
{  

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

    }      

    // Utility.method() used somewhere in FirstActivity
}

public class Utility {

    public static void method()
    {

    }  

}

public class SecondActivity extends Activity 
{  

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        Utility.method();

    }
}
```

Of course making it static depends on the use case.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {

static Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

    try {

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            String texto = bundle.getString("message");
            if (texto != null) {
              //code....
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void launch(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ActivityB.class);
        intent.putExtra("message", message);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

In ActivityA or Service.

```
public class Service extends Service{

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {    

        String text = "Value to send";
        ActivityB.launch(text);
        Log.d(TAG, text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Success for me:

```
Activity1:
public static ArrayList<String> listName;
public static void DeleteOneOfList(int position){
    listName.remove(position);
}

Activity2:
private Activity1 activity1;
activity1.DeleteOneOfList(position)
```

Answer (score -4):

Declare a SecondActivity variable in FirstActivity

Like this

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {  

SecondActivity secactivity;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);
  }      

  public void method() {
    // some code

  secactivity.call_method();// 'Method' is Name of the any one method in SecondActivity

  }  
}
```

Using this format you can call any method from one activity to another.

Comment: Please this answer should be updated, this solution isn't correct, you should always instanciate the SecondActivity object and that will not work !