# How to call function from different Component?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a basic class:

```
export default class Foo extends Component{
 constructor(props){}
 woop(){
  somethingimportanthappening..
 }
}
```

in the other component I import it like this:

```
import Foo from './Foo'
export default class Component2 extends Component{
 constructor(props){}

 randomfunction(){
   Foo.woop() // FAILS
 }
}
```

How can I call the function "woop" from the other component (Component2)? Foo.woop() isn't working ..

Comment: OK, blame me for being old fashioned, if you will, but I've not played around with new ES6 stuff, so I'm not totally clear what this does. Yet, I _think_ you're exporting a class `Foo` and `woop()` is an _instance method_. Hence, shouldn't you do `foo = new Foo(); foo.woop()`?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In React a component have an independent function, so in Foo component you define it, something like

```
export default class Foo extends Component{
  constructor(props){}
  woop(){
    somethingimportanthappening..
  }
  render() {
    <div>Class Foo</div>
  }
}
```

and when you want to use Foo component, you just import and use

```
<Foo />
```

and if you want to use a function in Foo component, you can define a reference to Foo

```
<Foo ref="foo" />
```

then use it by

```
import Foo from './Foo'
export default class Component2 extends Component{
  constructor(props){}

  randomfunction(){
    this.refs.foo.woop();
  }

  render() {
    return <Foo ref="foo" />
  }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me :)

Comment: True, this works quite well, but only with a parental relationship.. what if there isn't any?

Comment: @dv3 if you inherit a class, you can call parent function through super.methodName(), maybe works :D

Answer (score 1):

Since `woop` is not a `static` function you cannot `Foo.woop()`

You should instantiate a `Foo` instance as follows:

```
import Foo from './Foo'

export default class Component2 extends Component{
    private fooInstance: Foo;

    constructor(props){
      this.fooInstance = new Foo(props);
    }

    useFoo(){
      this.fooInstance.woop();
    }
}
```

Let me know if something is unclear :)

Comment: makes sense :) but it's throwing unexpected token on the 'private fooInstance: Foo;' line... *confused*

Comment: Try it without the private, it is just a recommendation. (assuming the unexpected token is the `private` and not something about the `: Foo` type)

Comment: 'Foo is not a constructor'... lol is this something react-native specific?

Comment: updated my answer, your `Foo` class should have a constructor for instantiating a new instance of it

Comment: Thanks but it already had a constructor in it.. didn't really change it..

Comment: Please share some more of the code so i can help you better :)

Comment: Updated my answer according to your new shared code, assuming the given `props` to the `Component2` is being forwarded to the constructor of the `Foo`, let me know if it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Creating an instance of a class to call a function seems wrong to me. I'm not sure but its like calling a function from different Activity inside another Activity in Android: [You can't and mustn't do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19666607/4306508)

Imo, the proper way to call a function of a different class to pass the function callback as props (if there is a parental relation). If there isn't any, triggering [Events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-events) using `react-native-simple-events` is fairly simple.

Alternatively, you can use [Redux](https://redux.js.org) which makes your app more robust. This may change and improve your overall app logic.