# Method from other activity is not Calling from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, methods, call

I am trying to Call method from **Another Activity** but it is not calling. When i use intent it works but when i call method it fails. The method which is in `onNotificationPosted()`. Here is the code

```
public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {

    Context context;
    private DatabaseReference dbref;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        dbref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        ChatActivity ch=new ChatActivity();
        ch.location();
      //  Intent n=new Intent(NotificationListener.this,ChatActivity.class);
        //startActivity(n);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.i("Msg","Notification Removed");
    }
}
```

The intent which is **commented** works but the method is not calling. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't look like you can instantiate an activity and call it's method like that. checkout this post for an explanation of your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666572/how-to-call-a-method-in-another-activity-from-activity

Comment: Thanks but i already viewed this post but no luck :(

Comment: I cannot make this actiivity as class because it is notificationListener

Comment: Please describe your use case a little. Why do you need to call the method from the `ChatActivity`. As far as I could understand, launching the `ChatActivity` suffices your purpose.

Comment: I dont want to start activity .. i only need to run the method in chat activity because that will run in background

Comment: You cannot simply call an @Override method.

Answer (score 0):

make the method static and then call it like

```
ChatActivity.ch();
```