# Can't call a method from outside of a java class

Tags: java, android, methods, call

I have a method name `checkForUpdate()` in `UpdateActivity.java`. It looks like this:

```
@NonNull
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
protected String checkForUpdate(int curVersionCode) {
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  ... 
}
```

I am trying to call it from anotherActivity. So I'm trying to use code like this:

```
private void callFromAnotherActivity() {
  UpdateActivity updateApp = new UpdateActivity();
  String result = updateApp.checkForUpdate(...);
}
```

so when I type `updateApp.` then a list of the methods of `UpdateActivity.java` appears but there is no `checkForUpdate()` method. Why?

Comment: First of all this is not proper way to use Activities. Both of your Activities are in same package?

Comment: Yes, they are in same package.

Comment: Can u share more code that you have written in firstActivity?

Comment: Yes, if necessary. Is it?

Comment: This will not work and really shouldn't because you DO NOT want create a new `UpdateActivity` Activity just to use a method that you wish to reuse. Methods like `checkForUpdate()` are worthy of their own class  if they are to be reusable.

Comment: change `checkForUpdate` to `public`

Comment: @john i did it but no result.

Comment: @Barns Why it wont work?

Comment: `callFromAnotherActivity` is a method or class ?

Comment: @JohnJoe A method.

Comment: same project, same package ?

Comment: Yes. Same project and same package.

Comment: please screen shot the project's structure

Comment: Ok. I think it is a long process. The code is not fully mine too. I'd rather try to get help from local source. Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: looks like you are missing both Java and Android basics like `Java access modifiers` and `Android Activities`. Please pass through some basic training before you continue

Answer (score 1):

> so when I type updateApp. then a list of the methods of UpdateActivity.java appears but there is no checkForUpdate() method. Why?

This is because your method is not public and probably you haven't import the `UpdateActivity`.

**Please be noted** that you can't create an Activity by calling the following:

```
UpdateActivity updateApp = new UpdateActivity();
```

You need to use something like this:

```
// context is your activity context.
Intent updateApp = new Intent(context, UpdateActivity.class);
context.startActivity(updateApp);
```

---

My suggestion:

You need to move the `checkForUpdate` method from `UpdateActivity` and make it as an util. So, other activity using the method won't be dependent and coupled with `UpdateActivity`. Localize the method to an utility class something like this:

```
public class UpdateUtil {

  ...

  @NonNull
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  public static String checkForUpdate(int curVersionCode) {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ... 

  }
}
```

and then use the method with:

```
UpdateUtil.checkForUpdate(1);
```

If you can't move the code (e.g, you don't have ownership of the code), you can do these things:

1. Make the `checkForUpdate` as static method
2. Use EventBus to tell the `UpdateActivity` to do the update.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to follow your suggestion. if succeed, i will let you know. You're right, i'm lacking some basic concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You should not create an instance of the activity class. It is wrong. Activity has ui and lifecycle and activity is started by startActivity(intent)
Check here : [call a method in another Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666572/how-to-call-a-method-in-another-activity-from-activity)