# Android Kotlin - How to Call Activity Method From Another Activity

Tags: android, function, kotlin, android-activity

I want to call a method in Activity1 from Activity2 with button click

```
class MainActivity1 : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

}

fun someFunction() { //... }
```

---

```
class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    btnClick.setOnClickListener {
        MainActivity1().someFunction()
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want to do, but I think it's the wrong way to go about it. This might be relevant to read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666572/how-to-call-a-method-in-another-activity-from-activity. You could also share data via a shared viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

Wite `someFunction()` inside companion object

```
 companion object {
        fun someFunction() {/*act like static method*/}
    }
```

Call it from another acitivity

```
MainActivity1.someFunction()
```