# Text to Speech producing error

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

So I am attempting to implement text to speech into my app for the first time ever.  I continue to get an error thought when the speech is called.  Here is the log that I am getting:

```
01-23 18:52:29.825: E/AndroidRuntime(24380): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 18:52:29.825: E/AndroidRuntime(24380): Process: com.rcd.league, PID: 24380
01-23 18:52:29.825: E/AndroidRuntime(24380): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 18:52:29.825: E/AndroidRuntime(24380):    at com.rcd.league.speakActivity.speakOut(speakActivity.java:60)
01-23 18:52:29.825: E/AndroidRuntime(24380):    at com.rcd.league.spawnTimers$15.onClick(Timers.java:350)
01-23 18:52:29.825: E/AndroidRuntime(24380):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
01-23 18:52:29.825: E/AndroidRuntime(24380):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18423)
01-23 18:52:29.825: E/AndroidRuntime(24380):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-23 18:52:29.825: E/AndroidRuntime(24380):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-23 18:52:29.825: E/AndroidRuntime(24380):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-23 18:52:29.825: E/AndroidRuntime(24380):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5083)
01-23 18:52:29.825: E/AndroidRuntime(24380):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 18:52:29.825: E/AndroidRuntime(24380):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-23 18:52:29.825: E/AndroidRuntime(24380):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-23 18:52:29.825: E/AndroidRuntime(24380):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-23 18:52:29.825: E/AndroidRuntime(24380):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my code:

```
package com.rcd.league;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;

public class speakActivity extends Activity  implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
    private TextToSpeech tts;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
        checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
                speakOut();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }

    }

    public void speakOut() {

        String text = "test";

        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }



}
```

I am calling speakOut(); from another activity.  Here is the clip of that code:

```
speakActivity speak = new speakActivity();
```

...

```
    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (btTimer.getText().toString().contains(":50")){
                        cd[0].start();
                        speak.speakOut();

                    } else {
                        cd[0].cancel();
                        cd[0].onFinish();
                    }

                }
            });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

EDIT: I have also tried QUEUE_ADD instead of QUEUE_FLUSH and that didnt work either :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created the `speakActivity` Activity, but in the code you have posted you never started the Activity. Because the activity was never started, `onCreate()` was never called and therefore `tts` is not initialized. That is why you get a `NullPointerException` when you call

```
tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

in `speakOut()`.

See this stackoverflow question for more information about when `onCreate()` is called: [Is onCreate called when an Activity object is created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475356/is-oncreate-called-when-an-activity-object-is-created)

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful actually, I think it has finally clicked what an Intent does.. however, should I startActivity(intent) in the onCreate of the first activity?

Comment: From the code I see it looks like you want this code to be called when the user clicks a button on the app right? So you would want to start the activity when the user clicks the button. Look at this tutorial for Starting An Activity in android. I think it is a good, more thorough, example of what you want to do that I can explain. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html